# How can i convert a List<Vector3> to a Mesh in Godot?

Tags: c#, mesh, godot, triangulation

I have a List of points. These points are `Vector3`.
Now i want to create a mesh out of these points.
I'm not sure how these points are called so i'll try to explain with this:

```
*----------*
|          |
|          |
*----------*
```

(Point is represented using `*`)
How can i do this using the Godot Engine?

Comment: `I believe 3D programs like Blender and most CAD programs do export the mesh's vertices in order?` Depends on the file format. You have to parse the file to generate those triangles.

Comment: This file is being parsed but the output are some file-specific entities which mostly store positions

Comment: Some formats do have how to make the triangles. Besides that, you probably have a list of triangles (each tree vertex is a new triangle). The other possibilities are not likely: A triangle fan (each triangle is the first vertex, the last vertex and the prior vertex) which is not likely because, it only makes fans. Or you have a triangle strip (each vertex is a new triangle reusing the past two vertex). If you have multiple vertex meant to be coplanar, then they can be unordered and you can use delaunay triangulation, but that is also unlikely because that only makes planar polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of triangles (each three vertex make up a new triangle), you can go ahead and use [`SurfaceTool`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_surfacetool.html#class-surfacetool).

It should be something like this:

```
var st = new SurfaceTool()
st.begin(Mesh.PrimitiveType.Triangles)
foreach (vertex in whatever_data_you_have())
{
    st.addVertex(vertex)
}

st.GenerateNormals();

st.Index();

mesh = st.Commit();
```

---

**Addendum**: So you don't have triangles. I would expect that the specification of the file format you are trying to parse says what is it you supposedly have. That would make things easier.

A couple things you can try to process this anyway:

- Identify when you have duplicated vertex. Identify if they come on a regular pattern.
- Identify when you are getting coplanar points and when not.

So, I would say, take the first distinct vertex, and use them to define a plane. And from there keep looking if other points are on the same plane or not. And once you find a point that is not on the same plane, try to triangulate the points you have. Define the new plane, and continue.

---

Say you have **distinct** vertex `A`, `B` and `C`. They are all, of course, points on a plane. The normal of the plane is:

```
var plane_normal = (B - A).cross(C - A).normalized();
```

To find the distance of the plane to the origin, project any of the points on the normal, and take the length:

```
var plane_distance = A.project(plane_normal).Length();
```

Now, we can check if a point `P` is on the plane, by comparing that distance:

```
var in_plane = Mathf.isEqualApprox(P.project(plane_normal).length(), plane_distance);
```

---

And we want to triangulate, so we are going to define a `Basis`. In particular we want to align one of the axis of the `Basis` with the normal of the plane. There are infinitely many possible `Basis` that satisfy that criteria, we don't care which one we get, as long as it is consistent.

So, I'll find out how to rotate `plane_normal` to `Vector3.BACK` (because it only has value on the z axis, so I can then discard it), and create a `Basis` from that rotation.

First of all, it could be that `plane_normal` is already `Vector3.BACK`, in which case we can use `Basis.IDENTITY`. If it isn't we want to find a rotation axis, and angle:

```
var basis = Basis.IDENTITY;
if (!plane_normal.isEqualApprox(Vector3.BACK))
{
    var rotation_axis = plane_normal.cross(Vector3.BACK);   
    var rotation_angle = plane_normal.signedAngleTo(Vector3.BACK, rotation_axis)
    basis = Basis.new(rotation_axis, rotation_angle)
}
```

---

Now we can convert our points to 2D on the plane:

```
var tmp = basis.xform(P3D);
var P2D = Vector2(tmp.x, tmp.y);
```

And back:

```
var tmp = Vector3(P2D.x, P2D.y, 0.0f);
var P3D = basis.xformInv(tmp);
```

Which means we can convert all the points on the plane to 2D, put them on an array, and then feed them to `Geometry.triangulatePolygon`. That should give you triangles. Still 2D, so convert them back to 3D, and feed them to the code I posted at the start of the answer which already knows how to deal with triangles.

Comment: I tried this on a cube but nothing is really happening. I have shared some screenshots using Google Photos. When i view the back of the cube, i do see some triangles but not really a cube. However when i set it to Mesh.PrimitiveType.Lines i do see a cube. cube-front: https://photos.app.goo.gl/7kenf1XXpD1W6ZDv9 cube-back: https://photos.app.goo.gl/N7vt1ZC2dXTZJ1oT7 Mesh.PrimitiveType.Lines: https://photos.app.goo.gl/miK846Ao9MqFiwhX6

Comment: @MomoVR So you don't have triangles. I don't know if they are polygons, or quads… But if you want triangles, you are going to have to convert them, and that depends on what exactly do you have.

Comment: What i am trying to do is importing step (.stp) files which are a CAD file format. Apparently these files don't use triangles. Altough i'm using a C# library called [ixmilia step](https://github.com/ixmilia/step)  which gives me a bunch of Step-Entities, mostly with their own coördinates. I was using these for the vertices.

Comment: @MomoVR I don't know how those work. However, I just finished expanding the answer, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Okay, i was trying to implement this but i don't really know how i could get those vertices. So just to make sure i understand what youre explaning: 1. Loop over vertices and generate planes. 2. Convert these planes into 2D. 3. Triangulate these 2D planes. 4. Convert the triangles back to 3D.

Comment: @MomoVR You need to identify the planes, so you can convert the vertex to 2D projected on those planes. Once you all the vertex that belong to a plane, you do that projection to 2D, where you can triangulate the vertex, which gives you triangles, but still 2D. So convert them back to 3D. To be clear, you need at least three (distinct) vertex for a plane, but you want to include all consecutive vertex that are on the same plane (removing duplicate vertex). So it is one plane for many vertex. And you don't convert the plane to 2D, you convert the vertex to 2D according to the plane they are on.